# R: Identify the first occurrence of two consecutive days without observation for each ID

Tags: r

I have a data frame with ID, date and observation, and I want to find the first occurrence of two consecutive days without observation for each ID.

Example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), Date = c(1,2,4,2,3,6), Observation = c(1,1,2,1,2,4) )
```

Desired result:

```
ID   Date
1    5
2    4
```

While I could make it work with some dirty code, it's awkward, and I would like to have a more generalized solution.

My code:

```
require(dplyr)
dftemp <- merge(distinct(df, ID), data.frame(Date = c(1:100)))
#Date in the real data frame is always between 1~90, so I choose 100. Probably not true for other data frames.
dftemp <- left_join(dftemp, df)
dftemp$marker <- is.na(dftemp$Observation)
dftemp <- arrange(dftemp, ID, Date)
dftemp$marker2 <- dftemp$marker + c(dftemp$marker[-1], 0) #Shift by 1 row, then add up.
dftemp %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter( marker2 == 2) %>% summarize(Date = min(Date)) %>% as.data.frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one thought using `tidyverse` package. Perhaps, remove rows with missing observations (`NA`). Then, for each `ID`, determine the difference between dates. The "First Occurrence" of 2 days without observation would be either the day after the first of two days where the difference is > 2, or the day after the last day.

**Edit**: Added `arrange` to ensure that it is sorted by `Date`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  drop_na(Observation) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(DateDiff = c(0, diff(Date))) %>%
  summarise(FirstOccur = ifelse(any(DateDiff > 2), Date[which(lead(DateDiff) > 2)] + 1, last(Date) + 1))
```

**Output**

```
     ID FirstOccur
  <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1          5
2     2          4
```

Comment: The Date need to be sorted before fed to mutate. Otherwise, the result would not be correct for ```data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), Date = c(4,1,2,2,3,6), Observation = c(1,1,2,1,2,4) )``` But the essence of the solution is there. Thanks.